# Datetick take into account NaN in plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a series `y` that contains values, some of which are `NaN` some numeric (double).

The series has an associated vector `d` which contains the `datenum` dates.

Example:

```
y=[NaN(5,1); rand(10,1)]
d=now-14:now
```

When I run:

```
plot(d,y)
```

I get the graph I want; the NaN observations are taken out.

However, when I run:

```
plot(d,y); datetick
```

then my graph starts from the beginning and takes into account all the observations (even when `y` is a `NaN`).

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Why not just remove the NaNs? `plot(d(isfinite(y)), y(isfinite(y)); datetick`

Comment: This seems to be a kind of bug/inconsistency of matlab. Naveh's workaround seems appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html) we can see that there is an easy way (shown below) to preserve the current axes limits.

```
plot(d,y);
datetick('keeplimits');
```

The `'keeplimits'` argument does exactly what it suggests, maintaining the x-axis limits whilst converting the tick values to dates. You may also want to pass `'keepticks'` to preserve tick mark locations.

---

The behaviour you describe seems contrary to the docs:

> `datetick` selects a label format based on the minimum and maximum limits of the specified axis.

From this statement I would expect the values to remain the same, but there is obviously something about the way the limits are handled internally which means the `NaN` points are included. At least we are given a simple work around!

Comment: I do not agree that it is expected/consistent behaviour. The default x limits do not take `NaN` into account while `datetick` does. Nevertheless, at least a nice workaround. `'keeplimits'` is useful when you set the range manually.